# Limit of a Sequence involving cubic root

Tags: sequences-and-series

I succeed in finding the following limit applying binomials and squeeze theorem:
$$\lim(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) = \lim\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} = 0$$ because $0 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

But I need help because I'm not finding any way to simplify and solve the following limit:
$$\lim(\sqrt[3]{1-n^3} + n)$$

Comment: Is this the limit as n tends to infinity?

Comment: Yes, it's the limit of a sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$(a^3+b^3)=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on this ? I'm really trying to solve through that way, since the other answers are not in my level.

Comment: Oh, I get it, thank you.

Comment: @OtávioRapôso I am interested in how this helped you to solve the problem - what did you do with it?

Comment: a + b is the content of the limit. Multiply by (a² - ab + b²) in the numerator and denominator. You will find 1 in the numerator and a positive number in the denominator that increases with n. Then, the limit is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Either:
$$
n-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}=n-n\cdot\sqrt[3]{1-\frac1{n^3}}=n-n\cdot\left(1-\frac13\frac1{n^3}+o\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)\sim\frac1{3n^2}\to0.
$$
Or:
$$
n-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}=\int_{n^3-1}^{n^3}\frac{\mathrm dx}{3x^{2/3}}\leqslant\int_{n^3-1}^{n^3}\frac{\mathrm dx}{3(n^3-1)^{2/3}}=\frac1{3(n^3-1)^{2/3}}\sim\frac1{3n^{2}}\to0.
$$
Or: @Babak's hint.

Comment: Nice trick with the integral. First time I ever saw something like that.

Comment: @GitGud: Did always makes solutions like it. Did really did it. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

We have $(1+x)^\alpha\sim_0 1+\alpha x$
so

$$\sqrt[3]{1-n^3}+n=n\left(1-(1-\frac{1}{n^3})^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\sim_\infty \frac{1}{3n^2}\to0$$

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}$ is awfully close to $n$ when $n$ is large. For a crude estimate, note that 
$$\left(n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^3=n^3-3n+\frac{3}{n}-\frac{1}{n^3}\lt  n^3 -1$$ if $n\ge 2$. It follows that if $n\ge 2$ then 
$$ 0\lt  n-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1} \lt n-\left(n-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n},$$
and the rest follows by Squeezing.